# How to get value of selected option in react-bootstrap select FromControl

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to write what the user selects from a dropdown to a firebase database based off the value stored in the component state, but I can't figure out how to get the value of the selected option and update it to the `storeType` state

Here is my dropdown menu:

```
<FormGroup>
                        <FormControl
                            componentClass="select"
                            placeholder="Store type"
                            onChange={this.handleCatChange}
                        >
                            <option value="placeholder">Choose eatery type...</option>
                            <option value="cafe">Cafe</option>
                            <option value="bakery">Bakery</option>
                            <option value="pizza">Pizza store</option>
                            <option value="sushi">Sushi store</option>
                            <option value="buffet">Buffet</option>
                            <option value="donut">Donut store</option>
                            <option value="other">Other</option>
                        </FormControl>
</FormGroup>
```

**this.handleCatChange:**

```
handleCatChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        storeType: e.target.value
    })
    console.log(this.state.storeType)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your state is valid, but not when you do your `console.log`. It's because `setState` is asynchronous and does not mutate immediately your state values.

According to [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate),

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains.

If you need to ensure ordering of events after a setState call is made, you can pass a callback function.

#### this.handleCatChange

```
handleCatChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        storeType: e.target.value
    }, () => console.log(this.state.storeType))
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I understand now

Answer (score 1):

> you need to bind your function like this ..

```
 onChange={this.handleCatChange.bind(this)}



    constructor () {
        super();
        this.state = { 
          storeType: '' 
        };
      }


    handleCatChange(e) {
    const type = e.target.value;
        this.setState({
            storeType:type 
        });

    }
```