# why updated states are not logging on the console

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to log the updated values of state after setState. But they are not updating. can anyone tell me why? The updated values of states can be seen in render function but not in the tokenAccess() method.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.authUrl=this.authUrl.bind(this);
        this.tokenAccess=this.tokenAccess.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            access_token:'',
            token_type:'',
            expires_in:''
        }
    }

    tokenAccess(){
        const hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
        const hashArr = hash.split(/[=&]/);
        console.log(hashArr);
        this.setState({
            access_token: hashArr[1],
            token_type: hashArr[3],
            expires_in: hashArr[5],
        })
        console.log(this.state);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.tokenAccess();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <a href={this.authUrl()}>LOGIN</a>
                <div>
                    {
                        this.state.access_token
                    }

                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React slow setState at console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45622879/react-slow-setstate-at-console-log)

Comment: ugh, should have been https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/setstate-doesnt-update-the-state-immediately

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setState doesn't update the state immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/setstate-doesnt-update-the-state-immediately)

Comment: setState is asynchronous, it takes some time to mutate the state. Hence it may not be available immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `callback`,  change your `setstate` like this

```
  this.setState({yourdata:"newdata"},
   ()=>console.log(this.state.yourdata))
```

If your state is still empty then maybe your `hashArr` has problem and you should check it out

Hope you get the idea and it works for you

Comment: Almost `this.setState({yourdata:"newdata"},
   ()=>console.log(this.state.yourdata))`

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is an asyncronous method, which means that the effect is not immediate. That is why you should pass the code you want to execute after as second parameter (callback) : `setState(updater[, callback])` ([source](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)).

```js
tokenAccess(){
    const hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    const hashArr = hash.split(/[=&]/);
    console.log(hashArr);
    this.setState({
        access_token: hashArr[1],
        token_type: hashArr[3],
        expires_in: hashArr[5],
    }, () => {                   // This is the
        console.log(this.state); // callback as
    })                           // second parameter
}
```