# Recurring function with useState - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion

I have read up on [hashing iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348109/is-double-hashing-a-password-less-secure-than-just-hashing-it-once) and although this is not a question about security I can´t seem to find information on how to actually do this correct.

I thought that when in React, this should be done with `useState`, but im clearly missing something here.

Full code:

```
import { sha256 } from "js-sha256";
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [currentHash, setCurrentHash] = useState("summer1");

  function iterate(iterations) {
    for (let x = 0; x < iterations; x++) {
      setCurrentHash(sha256(currentHash)); //Does 1 hash only
      console.log("Hashed", x, "times"); //Logs 4 times
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
     
        <button onClick={() => iterate(4)}> Klick</button>
        currentHash: {currentHash}
        {/* Correct hashes */}
        <p>0: summer1</p>
        <p>1: {sha256("summer1")}</p>
        <p>2: {sha256(sha256("summer1"))}</p>
        <p>3: {sha256(sha256(sha256("summer1")))}</p>
        <p>4: {sha256(sha256(sha256(sha256("summer1"))))}</p>
 
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling setState in a loop only updates state 1 time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248748/calling-setstate-in-a-loop-only-updates-state-1-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sha256(currentHash)` is going to give you the same result no matter how many times you run it.

[`currentHash` won't be updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45622879/react-slow-setstate-at-console-log) until the component is re-rendered and a new value is pulled out of the state and assigned to the new instance of `currentHash` at the top of the function.

You need to:

1. store the result in a variable — not the state
2. use the value of that variable as the input to the function
3. store the final result in the state at the end

Comment: No, it actually updates correctly (hashes) every time I run the function.

Comment: @RustyJames — If it updated "correctly" then your comment — `//Does 1 hash only` — would say that it does it 4 times.

Comment: But the for-loop has no effect on the state change, except the first time.

Comment: @RustyJames — Because every time the four loop iterates it pulls in the same value of `currentHash` as I said in this answer.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you, it works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
import { sha256 } from "js-sha256";
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [currentHash, setCurrentHash] = useState("");

  function iterate(input, iterations) {
    for (let x = 0; x < iterations; x++) {
      input = sha256(input);
      console.log("Hashed", x, "times");
    }
    setCurrentHash(input)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      
        <button onClick={() => iterate("summer1", 2)}> Klick</button>
        currentHash: {currentHash}

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```